# what is the the difference between all the NSS caching daemons?

Tags: ldap, unix, cache

I would like to see a comparison between [nscd](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nscd) (part of [glibc](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc)), [unscd](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unscd), [nsscache](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nsscache), [sssd](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/sssd) and [nss-pam-ldapd](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nss-pam-ldapd). Those are all the alternatives to nscd that i could find in Debian...

Our setup is that we have a bunch of workstations connected to an LDAP server. Right now we are seeing issues with nscd that seems to be having trouble on boot (as mentionned [in the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS#Configuring_LDAP_Authentication)). In fact, it just seems to completely disappear and is generally unreliable. What about the others? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: I can't tell you much about it, but I've read somewhere that Centos/Redhat switched to sssd from nscd because stability and scalability. Please read this: http://www.techrockdo.com/linux/centos-authentication-with-sssd . The main reason if I recall correctly was to eliminate using of winbind in AD environment.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski looks like the start of an answer to me. also, internal note: this is ticket RM#17874 on our side.